# How to configure Firefox to handle text/foo internally?

Tags: firefox, mime-types

I frequently would like to display text-like content (e.g. `text/turtle`) directly in the browser (i.e. without downloading it or opening it in a separate text editor).

Is there a way to configure Firefox to display `text/*` content?

Answer (score 0):

This article describes the MIME type handling in Firefox.  it basically comes down to using the preferences > Applications tab to edit the action for the appropriate content type.  there is no option to add a content type but once you download a file of that content type it *should* be added to this list.

http://mzl.la/1xKrEoo

> **Adding, removing, or editing a download action**
>
> The Applications panel has limited functionality for editing. You can change the action for an existing file type but you cannot add or remove file types. Entries are added automatically when you download files and select actions for them. See Adding download actions.

Comment: Just saw this on the site so it may not support "preview" for custom content types.   <br/>
  
To change how Firefox handles a file type in the list, click on its name to select it. Open the drop-down menu to select the download action you want Firefox to use:  

    **Preview in Firefox**: Select it if you want Firefox displays the content. It's only applicable to a limited number of types, those that Firefox is able to decode such as Podcast, Video Podcast, Web Feed, PDF.